# Method of Achieving sliding images effect on window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to recreate something similar to the pencil effect on:
http://www.fiftythree.com/pencil

Not exactly but similar.  About halfway down the current page, the pencil sort of pulls apart with a description on each part as the user scrolls down the window.

I am attempting to use the jquery `.animate` function to pull multiple div's apart in the same fashion.

IE: (image1) behind that (image2) behind that (image3).

Sort of a vertical accordion effect.
I am basing everything off scrollTop variable.  And at certain points it will move the div's in a different fashion.  All the events are contained in this loop.

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {

    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    // doing stuff

}
```

My issue is that the scrolling function is not executing fast enough.  If I scroll slowly it works, if I scroll quickly it sort of tries to play catch up and is either off location or too jerky.

Do you all think this is a decent way to achieve this effect, and if so - any suggestions on setting the refresh time to check for where the user has scrolled on the page?

Comment: Can you add more code, such as the relevant HTML and contents of your scroll handler in a runnable code snippet? Otherwise this will be difficult to answer.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for the reply.  Sorry about that.  This is pretty barebones at the moment - i'm just trying to figure out if jquery is the best method to accomplish this.  I'll edit.

This is a test with 4 boxes.  If you scroll slowly, it works.  If you scroll quickly, it starts messing up.  It's not refreshing my window scroll event quick enough.

http://test.sociallypresent.co/wp-admin/test/demo.html 

The code is too long to paste, but everything is visible in the source.  I just started the project, and am not sure if I am going about it the right way.

Comment: If you'd add a pen or fiddle, we'd be able to help out a lot more. Here's a start with some optimised lines : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVgMyG?editors=001.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry i'm new to posting on here.

Comment: What browser are you referring to? I think it actually works quite nicely, apart maybe from Firefox with smoothscroll where it's interrupted a lot. The example page at the top of your post doesn't look like a continuous animation but a 'sudden' change depending on each new scroll position. Here's some more improvement to the code and style : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvNLMY?editors=001.

Comment: I haven't error checked Firefox yet, but in everything else it is working much better.  I felt the same about their method, it appears almost as an event triggered by a certain scroll position, but its quite smooth in execution.